# How to specify an exam question continues - not inside the footer or header

Tags: exam

I am using Latex Exam to produce an exam that contains a multi-part question. I would like to put a notification under the last line of the question on a page saying "Question xx continues on the next page.". I know that you can use "ifcontinuation" or "continuedquestion" - but as far as I can follow the documentation the notification needs to belong in a header or a footer. Is there any way to place the notification above the footer?

Comment: The short answer is yes.

Answer (score 1):

This uses a footnote to add the warning.  `\Continued` must be added before the page break (with room to spare).

I can't find the source for `\@makefntext` to figure out where the indentation is coming from.

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\Nextpage}{\bgroup
  \advance\count0 by 1
  \thepage
\egroup}

\newcommand{\Continued}{\let\oldmakefnmark=\@makefnmark
  \let\@makefnmark=\relax% remove footnotemark
  \footnotetext{Continued on page \Nextpage}%
  \let\@makefnmark=\oldmakefnmark}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{45\baselineskip}
\begin{questions}
\Continued
\question \blindtext
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```